# How to achieve XML parsing in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Currently I am working with XML parsing in Android. I don't know how it is working. I am using the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(MobileServiceConst.URL);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("method", new StringBody(MobileServiceConst.UPLOAD_CONTACTS));
reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(Constants.userData.getUserInfo().getuserId())));
reqEntity.addPart("accesstoken", new StringBody(Constants.userData.getMYToken()));
reqEntity.addPart("data",new StringBody(jsnConts.toString()));
reqEntity.addPart("device_id",new StringBody(regId));
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);


HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));



StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {

           s = s.append(sResponse);

    }

sResponse = s.toString();

System.out.println("responseeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+sResponse);
```

The **sResponse** is in the following format:

```
<CS_Mservice_Main generator="check" version="1.0">
<getContacts>
<mycnt>
<key_0>
<id>1</id>
<user_id>22434</user_id>
<device_id>121212,</device_id>
<contact_id></contact_id>
<firstname></firstname>
<lastname></lastname>
<email></email>
<email1></email1>
<email2></email2>
<contact1>9809788201</contact1>
<contact2></contact2>
<contact3></contact3>
<contact4></contact4>
<created_at>2013-03-18 13:29:12</created_at>
</key_0>
<key_1>
<id>16</id>
<user_id>17025</user_id>
<device_id>APA91bGRyoeOlxZjhfjkdshjsdfsdsdf9kICZFsveU_QonqbNIbYONWLtiHpT4CmPe1aJg3rZ86noqj2HKshgZRlk1dc0Em7AVte2usHaP-qRzVBcP8BWzJuXa8ozA</device_id>
<contact_id></contact_id>
<firstname>Rahul</firstname>
<lastname>Jain</lastname>
<email>rahul.jain@abc.in</email>
<email1></email1>
<email2></email2>
<contact1></contact1>
<contact2></contact2>
<contact3></contact3>
<contact4></contact4>
<created_at>2013-03-18 13:30:04</created_at>
</key_1>
</mycnt>
<email/>
<sms/>
<status>success</status>
</getContacts>
</CS_Mservice_Main>
```

How can parse this format?

Comment: Any reason why http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html
Wont work ?

Comment: which tags you want parse and display in your phone?

Comment: i need to parse all details and store it in separate array list

Comment: CHECK THIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453516/xml-parsing-encoding-utf-8-utf-8/13454162#13454162, please google first then post a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.StringReader;

 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

 public class SimpleXmlPullApp
 {

     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
         System.out.println("End document");
     }
 }
```

try this for xml parsing in android.for more check this link

> http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 1):

Define a new Parser Class like this and implement this class where ever you require XML Parsing
public class XMLParser {

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;
}

public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
    Node child;
    if( elem != null){
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
            for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
} 

}
```

Now you need to call this Parsing Class and it will accept URL as input and return document object as a result

If XML Resource is static than you have to put XMl in Res Folder otherwise you can follow this structure

Make an object of XMLParser class like this

```
parser = new XMLParser();
xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
```

Than take a hashmap and store the output from respective Tags

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(KEY_ID, "ID id:" +parser.getValue( e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, "Name" + parser.getValue( e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue( e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, "Desc:  "+ parser.getValue( e, KEY_DESC));



            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

        }
        getXML();
```

You can also take help from this tutorial [Source](http://sumitsharma1900.blogspot.in/2013/03/xml-parsing-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML content and get Dom Element.

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
```

Comment: 03-19 10:16:18.425: I/System.out(10063): Docccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccorg.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl@42381c78   ,i got the doc,then next stage what i want to do?